# Script is trying to move a directory instead of a file - need assistance

Tags: linux, bash

The script appears to be correct. However, after FTP'ing all the files in the directory, it gives me the error that it is trying to move a directory into a directory of itself.

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

```
mysql -u ????? -p????? -h ????? db < $SCRIPT_FOLDER/script.sql  > script.xls

echo "###############################################################################"
echo "FTP the files"

#for FILE in `ls $SOURCE_FOLDER/`
for FILE in $SOURCE_FOLDER/*.xls


do
        echo "# Uploading $SOURCE_FOLDER/$FILE" >> /tmp/CasesReport.copy.out
    sshpass -p ???? sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - user@ftp  << END
         cd /source/directory/ 
         put $SOURCE_FOLDER/$FILE 
bye
END

echo "Moving $FILE to $SOURCE_FOLDER/history/"
mv  $SOURCE_FOLDER/$FILE $SOURCE_FOLDER/history/$FILE
```

Comment: got spaces in your file/dir names?

Comment: As @MarcB mentioned.  To correct for this, put your move parameters in quotes: `mv "$SOURCE_FOLDER/$FILE" "$SOURCE_FOLDER/history/$FILE"`

Comment: no spaces in the file names

Answer (score 1):

`$FILE` already contains `$SOURCE_FOLDER`, so you `put` command is doubling the path.

Example

```
$ cd /tmp
$ touch foo.txt bar.txt
$ cd
$ SOURCE_FOLDER=/tmp
$ for FILE in $SOURCE_FOLDER/*.txt; do echo "put $SOURCE_FOLDER/$FILE"; done
put /tmp//tmp/bar.txt
put /tmp//tmp/foo.txt
```

Inside the for loop, just use `"$FILE"`